# Python unpacking list: can't use starred expression

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to list all mountpoints that start with "\t":

```
with open("/proc/mounts") as f:
    mountpoints = (
        [list((filter(lambda s: s.startswith("/t"), line.split(" "))))
         for line in f if
        (lambda l:
         list(filter(lambda x: x.startswith("/t"), l))
        )(line.split(" "))])
    


print(mountpoints)
#[['/tmp']]
#this is correct, however I want to remove one pair of brackets

print(*mountpoints)
#['/tmp']
#this works!

m = *mountpoints
#SyntaxError: can't use starred expression here
#but this doesn't.
```

Why is the last assignment not working?
What is the difference to the print-statement?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Do you want unpacking, or just the first item of the list? Did you mean ‘ m = mountpoints[0]’?

Comment: You must unpack *into* something – arguments are implicitly "several things", but assignment sources are not. The correct syntax would be ``m = *mountpoints,`` (note the trailing comma) but what you seem to want is ``m, = mountpoints`` (note the trailing comma on the left-hand-side).

Comment: Why are you using filter like this in a list comprehension? List comprehensions are supposed to *replace* map/filter

Comment: @quamrana yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: What would you suggest? I don't know how I could replace them.

Comment: `yes, that's what I meant` - Or `m,*_ = mountpoints`

Comment: Something like `[[s for s in line.split() if s.startswith("/t")] for line in f if any(s for s in line.split() if s.startswith("/t"))]` but honestly you should probably just use a for-loop to avoid iterating over your line twice (and because it's becoming unreadable)

Comment: So for example, to avoid iterating twice, you can do something like: `[filtered for line in f for filtered in [[s for s in line.split() if s.startswith("/t")]] if filtered]` but again, this is just becoming unwieldy. A for-loop statement would be much better.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think I finally understood how this works. I think, this is even simpler:
`[entry for line in f for entry in line.split() if entry.startswith("/t")]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`*` unpacking "spreads" the iterable into an enclosing "container". For the call to `print`, the container is the parenthesis of the function call. With `m = *mountpoints` though, the right-hand side isn't inside of anything, so it can't be unpacked. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists):

> An asterisk * denotes iterable unpacking. Its operand must be an iterable. **The iterable is expanded into a sequence of items, which are included in the new tuple, list, or set, at the site of the unpacking**.

If you want to remove a level of nesting, and the inner list will always contain one element, you can just index it:

```
m = mountpoints[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Look on [itertools module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) of python, you can use chain.from_iterable(mountpoints) to solve your problem.

```py
from itertools import chain
points = chain.from_iterable(mountpoints)
```